# React application built on top of firebase renders 404 on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, firebase-hosting, custom-error-pages

We have a React App built on top of firebase. The problem we are facing is if you change the url by navigating to a different page other than the root `'/'`, then refresh the page, it displays a `404` as seen below. But this only happens in production.

[image: 404]

my `firebase.json` look like the following:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"]
  }
}
```

and we are using `react-router` for navigation.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='/registration' element={<Registration />} />
  ...       
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include this in your firebase.json.

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```